# Maintain percentage between elements of a series

Tags: series-expansion

Doing some code and I am struggling to find the next formula.

I have a series that starts at a number X.

I want to have a increase of 10% between each consequent element of my series.

10 -> 11 -> 12,1 -> 13.31 each of the elements is increased by 1.1 from the previous element. IS there a way to calculate my element of the series N without iterating across my series?

Comment: `start=10; length = 5;NestList[# 1.1 &, start, length]`? also `start (1.1)^Range[0, length]`?

Answer (score 2):

To find the closed-form use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

t[n_, x0_] = 
 x[n] /. RSolve[{x[n] == 11/10 x[n - 1], x[0] == x0}, x[n], n][[1]]

(* (11/10)^n x0 *)
```

The initial sequence is

```
t[#, 10.] & /@ Range[0, 5]

(* {10., 11., 12.1, 13.31, 14.641, 16.1051} *)
```

For an arbitrary term

```
t[1000, 10.]

2.46993*10^42
```

Alternatively, starting with an initial sequence

```
seq = RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == 11/10 x[n - 1], x[0] == x0}, x, {n, 1, 5}]

(* {(11 x0)/10, (121 x0)/100, (1331 x0)/1000, (14641 x0)/10000, (
 161051 x0)/100000} *)
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence

```
t2[n_, x0_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* (11/10)^n x0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[gs]
gs[start_, rate_, length_] := start (1 + rate)^Range[0, length - 1]

gs[10, 1/10, 5]
```

> ```
> {10, 11, 121/10, 1331/100, 14641/1000}
> ```

```
gs[10., 1/10, 5]
```

> ```
> {10., 11., 12.1, 13.31, 14.641}
> ```

You can also use [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html):

```
ClearAll[rt, nl]
rt[start_, rate_, length_] := RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (1 + rate) a[n], 
   a[1] == start}, a, {n, 1, length}]

rt[10., 1/10, 5]
```

> ```
> {10., 11., 12.1, 13.31, 14.641}
> ```

```
nl[start_, rate_, length_] := NestList[# (1 + rate) &, start, length - 1]

nl[10., 1/10, 5]
```

> ```
> {10., 11., 12.1, 13.31, 14.641}
> ```